# Alligning subcaptions with subfloats

Tags: graphics

I am trying to have three subfloats in a figure environment side by side, but the captions of each float are not placed below each float. I would like to do it with these packages, as I have used them so far in my thesis. It works fine with only two floats.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Figures/K-means.png}\label{Clustering_a}}
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Figures/n_clusters=10.png}\label{Clustering_b}}
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    \subfloat[c]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Figures/Threshold=0.5.png}\label{Clustering_c}}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{Label}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly for me ( I used `example-images` of graphicx package as I don't have your images)! Please post a complete minimal working example that reproduce the problem, not just a snapshot .

Comment: I can't think of any way to achieve this effect, except possibly for floatrow.